# Как расширить ФС

Tags: ubuntu

столкнулся с проблемой, заказал расширение жесткого диска на сервере, тех поддержка сказала, что жесткий диск расширен, но в ISP manager отображается старый объем диска(500гб) и чтобы отображался новый объем, цитирую ответ тех поддержки "Чтобы отображался полный объем требуется расширить ФС"
Данная услуга и них платная и составляет 3к за 1 час работы
Я в этом мало, что понимаю, но хочется разобраться как это сделать самостоятельно

Вывод команд

```
root@194:~#lsblk                                                                                          
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT                                                                
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom                                                                            
vda    253:0    0    4T  0 disk                                                                           
├─vda1 253:1    0  499G  0 part /                                                                         
├─vda2 253:2    0    1K  0 part                                                                           
└─vda5 253:5    0  975M  0 part [SWAP] 

root@194:~# df -T                                                                                         
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on                                      
udev           devtmpfs   8194364        0   8194364   0% /dev                                            
tmpfs          tmpfs      1643088     8948   1634140   1% /run                                            
/dev/vda1      ext4     514943472 10091836 478670928   3% /                                               
tmpfs          tmpfs      8215432        0   8215432   0% /dev/shm                                        
tmpfs          tmpfs         5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock                                       
tmpfs          tmpfs      8215432        0   8215432   0% /sys/fs/cgroup                                  
tmpfs          tmpfs      1643088        0   1643088   0% /run/user/0 

root@194:~# fdisk -u /dev/vda1                                                                            

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.                                       
Be careful before using the write command.                                                                

/dev/vda1: device contains a valid 'ext4' signature; it is strongly recommended to wipe the device with wi
pefs(8) if this is unexpected, in order to avoid possible collisions

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.                                                     
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xfa2dad8c.
```

Пробовал вводить `resize2fs /dev/vda1`

```
root@194:~# resize2fs /dev/vda1                                                                           
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)                                                                           
The filesystem is already 130821632 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270595

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/116405 ?

Comment: @КириллМалышев спасибо, команда resize2fs не помогла, дополнил вопрос

Comment: 1. отключите использование swap с vda5. 2. удалите vda5. 3. удалите vda2. 4. увеличьте размер vda1, так, чтобы хватило для swap. 5. создайте раздел для swap. 6. создайте swap. 7. подключите его. 8. а вот теперь уже можно воспользоваться resize2fs. 9. в следующий раз создавайте раздел для swap в начале диска.

Comment: другой вариант: 1. создайте раздел на свободном месте. 2. создайте на нём файловую систему. 3. используйте её.